# How to convert Varchar to Int in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Filtered index :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [FILTEREDIDX_MYTable_OID] 
ON [dbo].[MYTable] (column3 ASC)
   INCLUDE (column1, column2) 
   WHERE (column3 IN ((1), (2), (3)))
```

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[funcTest]
    (@list as varchar(8000), @delim as varchar(10))
RETURNS @lTable table(Value INT)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @DelimP INT    
   SET @DelimP = CHARINDEX(@delim, @list)

   WHILE @DelimP > 0
   BEGIN    
       INSERT INTO @lTable(Value) 
       VALUES(CAST(RTRIM(LEFT(@list, @DelimP - 1)) AS INT))    

       SET @list = right(@list, len(@list) - @DelimP)
       SET @DelimP = CHARINDEX(@delim, @list)
   END

   IF len(@list) > 0
      INSERT INTO @lTable(Value)
      VALUES(CAST(RTRIM(@list) AS INT))

   RETURN
END
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetList]
    @ParameterString varchar(8000)
AS                              
BEGIN                              
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT column1, column2 
    FROM MYTable 
    WHERE column3 IN (SELECT Value 
                      FROM funcTest(@ParameterString,','));
END
```

When I used the table valued function, the query is ok but the filtered index will not be used.

I would like to use the filter index in column3(int data type) to reduce logical reads.

If we only use the parameter, the filtered index will be used.

```
Exec sp_GetList '1,2,3'
```

> Error : SELECT column1, column2 FROM MYTable WHERE column3 IN
>   (@ParameterString);

-- because `@ParameterString` is `varchar`.

```
SELECT column1, column2 
FROM MYTable 
WHERE column3 IN ('1,2,3');
```

> Error message : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,3' to data type int.

OK    :

```
SELECT column1, column2 
FROM MYTable 
WHERE column3 IN (1,2,3);
```

How should I solve this problem ?

Comment: So you have observed from the query plan that the filtered index is not being used? What happens if you load the function result into a table variable then join to that table variable in your SP? This might also be a case of parameter sniffing - the SP has cached a plan that does not use the filtered index and it sticks with that plan.

Comment: If my answer below accurateky reflects the soution, please mark as answered

Comment: Thanks Nick, it still didn't use the filtered index. How can i do to use the filtered index ?

Comment: Your prior comment said it did? I suggest you do some research on parameter sniffing and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per comment...

Try loading the results of the function into a table variable and join to that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetList]
@ParameterString varchar(8000)

AS                              
BEGIN                              
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @T Table (Value INT)

INSERT INTO @T(Value)
SELECT DISTINCT Value FROM funcTest(@ParameterString,',')

SELECT column1, column2 
FROM MYTable 
INNER JOIN @T T
ON T.Value = column3 

END
```